# Distinct not working for ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin

I am trying to remove duplicates from an ArrayList in Kotlin. First of all I am getting a sortedNews from somewhere else and then I am adding it to the list called newsItems and then I am trying to remove the duplicates but the duplicates are still there. What am I doing wrong here

```
sortedNewsItems = nsItems!!.sortedWith(compareByDescending({it!!.timeStamp}))
        newsItems?.addAll(sortedNewsItems!!)
        newsItems?.distinct()
        Log.e("first item name ",sortedNewsItems?.get(0)?.title)
        recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Not sure completely but `newsItems?.distinct()` returns new instance of collection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`distinct` does not remove duplicates from the collection, it returns a new collection with duplicates removed. You're ignoring the return value of `distinct`, so the call has no effect.

Comment: May you please share your solution?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro you should use the return value

`val newList = items.distinct()`

Comment: @MMoersalin Yeah, I was too much of a newbie to understand that LOL

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to, instead of `addAll` use the function `union`

```
val firstList: ArrayList = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val secondList: ArrayList = arrayListOf(1, 5, 6, 7, 8)

val addAllList = firstList.addAll(secondList) //1,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,8
val unionList = firstList.union(secondList) //1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

> **union** - Returns a set containing all distinct elements from both collections.
>
> The returned set preserves the element iteration order of the original
> array. Those elements of the other collection that are unique are
> iterated in the end in the order of the other collection.
>
> To get a set containing all elements that are contained in both
> collections use intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try **[toSet()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/to-set.html)**

```
val newItems = postList //postList id old list
newItems.addAll(_postList) // _postList is new list
postList = newItems.toSet().toMutableList()
```